# Dockerfile /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile not able to use npm

Following a Laravel GIS course (https://www.webgis.dev/posts/laravel-php-and-docker).

I've set up php-fpm official docker image running PHP and served through an Nginx proxy.

Next step is "However, we will need a few extra PHP extensions to run Laravel and Postgres. We will need to build our own PHP image based on the official one to do so. We will also install npm (nodejs) and composer in the development image."

Created Dockerfile and updated my docker-compose.yml to reference it.

docker-compose build pulls everything in but falls over after a couple of minutes with exit code: 127

```
#0 155.7 All settings correct for using Composer
#0 155.7 Downloading...
#0 156.5
#0 156.5 Composer (version 2.5.8) successfully installed to: /usr/bin/composer
#0 156.5 Use it: php /usr/bin/composer
#0 156.5
#0 156.6 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
```

The course is about 6 months old when the code worked.

Dockerfile contents`

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg curl wget ca-certificates unzip lsb-release \
    && wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libicu-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        nodejs \
        postgresql-client-15 \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql zip bcmath pcntl exif \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
        && npm install -g npm \
        && apt-get -y autoremove \
        && apt-get clean \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
        && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

WORKDIR /var/www/app
USER www-data
```

Comment: try to install npm before composer maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue with Python image before, and that time I successfully resolved it by switching to the bullseye-version image approach.

try this... successful

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-bullseye

...
```

Comment: Thanks.  What is the difference, what does bullseye do compared to original?